# Qt and Android 11: accessing file in download folder

Tags: android, qt, directory, storage, scoped

I developed an app using QT 5.15 that need to read some kind of files in Android Download folder.
All it's OK until Android 9.
In Android 10 I added the manifest flag "requestLegacyExternalStorage=true" and it works.
From Android 11 I can't access any files in Download folder. Only my app generated files can be read. But I need to import files downloaded from email or Google Drive.

This is related to the new Scoped storage policy but I can't find any example for QT.

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: I have faced with this issue, it may be a cheat but you could read file with InputStream from uri and then create a new file with read data in your externalFilesDir or other app folder. So you can use this newly created file then delete at the end of job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ertuzun Thanks for your answer. I'm newbie with QT. Could you provide some code as example? Thanks a lot

Comment: It's called request**Legacy**ExternalStorage !! It will not work when building against API Level 30 or above. Read up on the android documentation why this was implemented and why you can not and should not try to access the download folder without User Intent, when targeting recent Android versions. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 1):

In `Android 11` you can access `Download` folder, but only for the files
you've created.

**For all other files (i.e. ones you did not create)**:

I'm afraid, you'll have to use `SAF` (Storage Access Framework) in your case.

The problem that there is no Qt code can be available (until Qt Team implement it), because it must be implemented on `Java` side.

There is no native API (e.g. `C++`) is available. I.e. you can't use any `C++` functions to work with files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Storage Access Framework ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select a file from Download directory.